# A thread in my View component: when to stop the thread?

Tags: android, view

I created a View component for android. The component has its own thread to make background work. I start the thread in the View constructor.
Where should I stop the thread? Is onDetachedFromWindow a correct place to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it the following way provided the `Thread` has to be active during the time the `View` has a `Surface` and uses it for drawing:

```
public class MyView extends View {
    class MyThread extends Thread {
        private boolean mActive = true;

        public void run() {
            while (mActive) {
                doThings();
            }
        }

        public void terminate() {
            mActive = false;
        }

        private void doThings() {
            // the things your thread should do
        }
    }

    private MyThread mBackgroundOperation = null;

    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        mBackgroundOperation = new MyThread();
        mBackgroundOperation.start();
    }

    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        mBackgroundOperation.terminate();
        mBackgroundOperation = null;

        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }
}
```

If this is not the case (if the `Thread`'s lifecycle is not directly dependant of the use of the `View`'s `Surface` for drawing) I would think twice about handling it inside the `View`, and would maybe consider moving it to the `Activity` that uses this `View` instead. "Maybe" because this is a difficult thing to determine without knowing what this `Thread` actually does.

Comment: You are welcome, @user618525 ! It's a pleasure to be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

stop() method is `deprecated`. Check this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28java.lang.Throwable%29

you should get your work done and leave it, Android is smart enough to take care of it..

Answer (score 0):

The best time to stop a view updating is probably when it's no longer visible.  Your activity's onStop() method will be called when this happens, and from there you could call a method you write in your custom view to shutdown its update thread.

```
// Activity.java
public void onStop() {
   myThreadedView.shutdown();
   ... // rest of onStop() here
}

// ThreadedView.java
public void shutdown() {
   myViewThread.shutdown();
}

// ViewThread.java
bool stop = false;

public void shutdown() {
   stop = true;
}

public void run() {
   while (!stop) {
      updateView();
   }
}
```